# Couchbase N1QL combine subquery results

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I run three different N1QL query and it result look like below

First Result:

```
{
"clicks": 12688190,
"m": 2,
"revenue": 51668.07,
"y": 2016  }
```

Second Result :

```
{
"Signups": 45,
"m": 2,
"y": 2016  },
```

Third Result :

```
{
"Deposits": 1,
"m": 2,
"y": 2016  }
```

**I want output like below**

```
{
"Deposits": 1,
"clicks": 12688190,
"Signups": 45,
"m": 2,
"y": 2016  }
```

**How can I join this Differen result in N1QL ??**

Comment: Can you just do UNION ALL?

Comment: But I need result as all match year and month wise

Comment: How about combining UNION ALL with GROUP BY. E.g. 'select sum(deposits), sum(signups), sum(clicks), sum(revenue) from (<put UNION ALL query here>) GROUP BY y, m'

Comment: You need to edit the question and make it clear for anyone reading. As part of that, you should include sample input documents and sample final results. Not clear what you mean by "join different results".

Comment: Now I have improved my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine subquery results with Couchbase 4.5.1.

```
SELECT OBJECT_CONCAT( (subquery1)[0], (subquery2)[0], (subquery3)[0] );
```